# Import text to pandas dataframe, use shift, do operation, save to text

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with two columns and 135001 rows. First column is amplitude and second column is related time. I want to save some rows of the file which the amplitude change from zero to not zero. for this I am using an idea which when I test the code with a small simple data (which I produce the data in the code) it works fine but with my original data it is not working. Maybe the problem is related to reading the data. The simple data which I have is like:

```
0 11
2 12
3 13
1 14
0 15
1 16
0 17
0 18
```

and the output should be:

```
2 12
1 16
```

I can do this with this code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0,11],[2,12],[3,13],[1,14],[0,15],[1,16],[0,17],[0,18]])
>>> df['shift'] = df[0].shift(1)
>>> df
   0   1  shift
0  0  11    NaN
1  2  12    0.0
2  3  13    2.0
3  1  14    3.0
4  0  15    1.0
5  1  16    0.0
6  0  17    1.0
7  0  18    0.0
>>> df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])
   0   1
1  2  12
5  1  16
```

But when I want to apply this to my data file which is a text file the out put will be an empty file:

```
b= open ("39-1+2.txt", "r")
df= pd.DataFrame(b)
df['shift'] = df[0].shift(1)
df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])
df.to_csv('test1.txt', index=False, header=None)
```

Here is some rows of my data, and all are similar to this.

```
0.000000 00:04:07.680000
0.000000 00:04:08.320000
0.000002 00:04:08.960000
0.000002 00:04:09.600000
0.000000 00:04:10.240000
0.000000 00:04:10.880000
0.000000 00:04:11.520000
```

Comment: Tell us more about the input file. What does it look like? How is it delimited? My guess about the empty lines in your save file is just because you need to call `reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything right, you only need to make a really tiny change:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test1.txt', delimiter = ' ', header = None)
df= pd.DataFrame(b)
df['shift'] = df[0].shift(1)
# assign the new dataframe to df
df = df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])
df.to_csv('test1.txt', index=False, header=None)
```

### You just need to assign the value back again to df.

EDIT:

```
df = pd.read_csv('YourFileName', delimiter = ' ', header = None)
df['shift'] = df[0].shift(periods=1, fill_value=0)
# assign the new dataframe to df
df = df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])
df.to_csv('test1.txt', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: I applied this. Now the output file is completely empty. So maybe there is a problem in this line but I can not understand where is the problem: df = df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])

Comment: Then I need to see how `b` looks like. And also, why aren't you using `b = pd.read_csv("39-1+2.txt",skiprows = n, header = None)`? Where `n` is the number of rows you want to skip (if any), and `header` flag no, if your file only contains data.

Comment: Ok. I used this, but the out put is still empty. I think the problem is that it is reading the data column by column. It seems that it read all the data as one column.

Comment: Thank you it is working fine now. So my problem was about shifting? I did not set this " periods=1, fill_value=0" . So it was all the problem?

Comment: Most possibly, yes. But for me it was working fine even without that, so it could also be how you read the file. Note: I used `delimiter = ' '` that may be the issue as well.